# How to convert jpg and wav into mp4 with specific duration?

Tags: python, image, audio, video, ffmpeg

I have a `.jpg` and a `.wav` file. How can I join these two files into an `.mp4` file with let's say a duration of 13 seconds (which is the duration of the wave file)?

I should probably use `ffmpeg`, but there are many flags and parameters about which I have no idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered here: https://superuser.com/questions/1041816/combine-one-image-one-audio-file-to-make-one-video-using-ffmpeg

but to use it in python you run

```
import os 
os.system('ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.wav -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a copy -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest out.mp4')
```